# Convert onCallback to Async

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, async-await

**How could I convert the method:**

```
static void DoWork(Action<bool> onCompleteCallback)
{            
    Task doWork = new Task( ()=>Thread.Sleep(2000) );

    Action<Task> onComplete = (task) => {
        onCompleteCallback(true); // should execute on the main thread
    };

    doWork.ContinueWith(onComplete, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    doWork.Start();                        
}
```

**to Async.**

If I convert it to Async what will be the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the reason to use `async` and `await` is to avoid callbacks.  By using the new `async` support, your method itself can return a `Task` (or `Task<T>`), and you can just use `await` on it, avoiding the need to pass in a callback entirely.

If you wanted to use the new async/await setup, you'd write this as:

```
static Task DoWork()
{
     return Task.Run( () => /* Your work */ Thread.Sleep(2000) );            
};
```

The difference would actually be in how you call this.  Instead of using a callback, you'd just write:

```
await DoWork();
// Do your callback work here - it'll automatically be mapped into the right sync context and happen after the above completes
```

You could, of course, pass the callback in still, and write it as:

```
static async Task DoWork(Action<bool> onCompleteCallback)
{            
     await Task.Run( ()=>Thread.Sleep(2000) ); // Or use Task.Delay(2000) if you just want a pause...
     onCompleteCallback(true);
};
```

This just defeats the purpose (somewhat) of using the new support, as one of the main advantages is that you no longer need to pass around callbacks and turn your logic "inside-out".

Comment: There's a fairly important difference between the OP's `Task` usage and your `await` usage.  `await` forces the "continuation" (the code after the `await`) to execute on a specific thread--in the same way that the OP used TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: BTW, you're not really avoiding callbacks; you've just coded them differently--inline.  The compiler still breaks it up into callbacks and invokes them as callbacks.  The async/await syntax allows the code that will be called-back to be sequential with the other code.

Comment: @PeterRitchie As for your first comment - I don't see the difference.  By using await, I'm forcing back onto the Sync Context (just like the OP did by using a continuation).  For the second - it's more a matter of making your code not have to be "inside out" by handling the callback mechanism yourself.  Under the hood, yes, this is doing something very similar to the OP - but the code is far simpler and straightforward.

Comment: yes, there is no difference--which is the point.  You don't need to use FromCurrentSynchronizationContext, which means that if you *did* want the "callback" to not execute on the UI thread you'd have to do something differently.  No argument about simpler and straightforward; but, people need to know the implicit differences.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Okay - I think I misunderstood your comment because you said "there's a fairly important difference" :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally write:

```
static async Task DoWorkAsync(Action<bool> onCompleteCallback)
{            
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Simpler than starting a new task
    onComplete(true); // Will automatically be called on the original context
}
```

Note that your method *could* return `void`, but it's generally cleaner to return `Task` from async methods so that you can compose it with other async operations.

As noted in comments, you should see whether you can redesign your code so you don't need to pass in a callback though. We'd need more context about the calling code to advise you further though.

Comment: Wouldn't you normally want to avoid callbacks when using async/await?  A big advantage is the ability to remove the need for callbacks like this...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Agreed - this would be a sort of interim measure while gradually migrating the rest of the code base.

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this:

```
static Task DoWork(Action<bool> onCompleteCallback)
{            
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    onCompleteCallback(true);
}
```

It becomes simpler, actually.

Because your function was originally called from the UI thread you can just invoke the callback because your method executes on the UI thread already.

Comment: If it's not in the UI thread already then `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` won't put you in the UI thread.